# MatSelect value doesn't change after @Input value is changed

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hy, I am having trouble, with mat-select in Angular, can you please help me? So in mat-select, I have settled ng-model to quoteStatuses which I get from the parent component over @Input.After input is changed, the mat-select button doesn't change. The code is below. Thank you.

```
       <ng-container *ngIf="quoteStatuses">
           <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
               <mat-label>Quote Statuses</mat-label>
               <mat-select
                   formControlName="quotes"
                   multiple
                   [(ngModel)]="quoteStatuses"
               >
                   <mat-option
                       *ngFor="let defaultQuoteStatus of defaultQuoteStatuses"
                       [value]="defaultQuoteStatus"
                       >{{ defaultQuoteStatus }}
                   </mat-option>
               </mat-select>
           </mat-form-field>
       </ng-container>

   @Input() quoteStatuses!: string[] | null;

   @Output() confirmFilters = new EventEmitter();
   @Output() resetForms = new EventEmitter();

   defaultQuoteStatuses: string[] = [
       'inProgress',
       'pending',
       'approved',
       'accepted',
       'rejected',
       'cancelled',
   ];

   filtersForm = new FormGroup({
       quotes: new FormControl(this.quoteStatuses),
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should decide on what your "source-of-truth" should be. Currently you have bound your FormControl to your select as well as your input variable "quoteStatuses". If I replicate this I also get a warning in the console:

> It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName.
> Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with
> reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed
> in a future version of Angular.
> For more information on this, see our API docs here:
> https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Second part: Can you also show the part of your code where you pass `quoteStatuses` to your child component? I assume you are modifying the array instead of passing a new one.

If you are doing something like this in your parent component

```
this.childProp.push('pending');
```

You should switch to

```
this.childProp = [...this.childProp, 'pending'];
```

in order to trigger change detection.